# Loading related data in EF Core

Tags: c#, orm, entity-framework-core

I have a question about Entity Framework Core. Let's say there is a `DbContext` provides work with 2 entities:
`Person { int Id; int PassportId; Passport Passport }`
`Passport { int Id; int PersonId; Person Person}`

As a result of query

```
Person person = context.Person.Include(p => p.Passport).FirstOrDefault();
```

I get Person object (person) which refers to Passport's object. However, there is also reference to person from Passport object.

How? Why does implicit binding of a Passport object to a Person object provide? I seem it's due to the navigation properties and that they work both ways. Share information, please.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a circular reference, did you enabled Lazy-Loading?
If the reference it's causing an exception you can use this to avoid it.

```
services.AddMvc()
.AddJsonOptions(options => {
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```